# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. React Native FlatList using

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I encounter such an error when trying to use FlatList Comopent in React Native. The code I wrote is as follows:

```
import {
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import flatListData from "../../data/flatListData";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ExampleContainer from "../layouts/ExampleContainer";

const FlatListExample = () => {

  return (
    <ExampleContainer>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.flatlist}
        data={flatListData}
        renderItem={RenderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </ExampleContainer>
  );
};

const RenderItem = ({ item }) => {
  const [onPressed, setOnPressed] = useState("");
  const handlePress = (id) => setOnPressed(id);
  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.renderItemView,
        {
          backgroundColor: onPressed === item.id ? "#7B66FF" : "transparent",
        },
      ]}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(item.id)}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: onPressed === item.id ? "white" : "black",
          }}
        >
          {item.id}. {item.item}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default FlatListExample;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  renderItemView: {
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: "#5FBDFF",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  flatlist: {
    padding: 5,
    borderColor: "#7B66FF",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});
```

flatListData :

```
const flatListData = [
  {
    id: "1",
    item: "React Native",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    item: "React JS",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    item: "Next JS",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    item: "Node JS",
  },
];


export default flatListData
```

Although the code works correctly here, I get an error message in concole. What is the reason for this error and why can't I use it this way?

I want to make a FlatList application in React Native, but I get this error.

Comment: i dont see anything wrong here. it might be from another comp.

Comment: Yes, there is actually no error, but I get this error. React Nativ itself does not give any error. Only my project does not render and I get this error that I write in the console. I am currently running my project in the web browser, could it be an error caused by this. I don't think I'm getting the error from a different component. When I remove the state definition, my error disappears

Comment: show code for ExampleContainer

Comment: ```import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const ExampleContainer = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        paddingVertical: 20,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </View>
  );
};

export default ExampleContainer; ```

Comment: You should add your error

Answer (score -1):

you're using the hook useState inside a function renderItem, and this function is outside the component FlatlistComponent, you can't use a react hook outside a component, if you want to use the react hook outside the component you must create a custom hook, in any case, take a look at the official react documentation to lear the basics. try this:

```
  import {
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import flatListData from "../../data/flatListData";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ExampleContainer from "../layouts/ExampleContainer";

const FlatListExample = () => {
 const [onPressed, setOnPressed] = useState("");

  return (
    <ExampleContainer>
      <FlatList
        style={styles.flatlist}
        data={flatListData}
        renderItem={RenderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </ExampleContainer>
  );
};

const RenderItem = ({ item }) => {
  
  const handlePress = (id) => setOnPressed(id);
  return (
    <View
      style={[
        styles.renderItemView,
        {
          backgroundColor: onPressed === item.id ? "#7B66FF" : "transparent",
        },
      ]}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(item.id)}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: onPressed === item.id ? "white" : "black",
          }}
        >
          {item.id}. {item.item}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default FlatListExample;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  renderItemView: {
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: "#5FBDFF",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  flatlist: {
    padding: 5,
    borderColor: "#7B66FF",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: RenderItem is a functional component and is able to contain hooks

Comment: Yes,  I agree with you, it should work but it doesn't, I think the problem is caused by React Native

Comment: @Seyit YilMaz have you tried my solution, you're code it shouldn't work, like I said before renderItem is a function, isn't a component, you are breaking the react hook rules.  https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: I tried your rule and it works, but then it doesn't have the structure I want. Instead I decided to do it the way they do it on the website. But when I do it your way the code works correctly. I don't understand why RenderItem is not a component. After all, anything that returns a value in JSX format is a react component. Thank you for your help

Comment: An component isn't not only because return an jsx, it must be isolate from other components, so you can move the render item outside of the FlatListExample or in a separated file and you will be able to use the useState inside the render item, like I said before you must to understand the basics of the react. I hope this can helps